# Optimize a piece of code that uses map action

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

The following piece of code takes a lot of time on 4Gb of raw data in a cluster:

```
df.select("type", "user_pk", "item_pk","timestamp")
      .withColumn("date",to_date(from_unixtime($"timestamp")))
      .filter($"date" > "2018-04-14")
      .select("type", "user_pk", "item_pk")
      .map {
        row => {
          val typef = row.get(0).toString
          val user = row.get(1).toString
          val item = row.get(2).toString
          (typef, user, item)
        }
      }
```

The output should be of type `Dataset[(String,String,String)]`.

I guess that `map` part takes a lot of time. Is there any way to optimize this piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt the `map` is the problem, nonetheless I wouldn't use it at all and go with standard `Dataset` converter

```
import df.sparkSession.implicits._

df.select("type", "user_pk", "item_pk","timestamp")
  .withColumn("date",to_date(from_unixtime($"timestamp")))
  .filter($"date" > "2018-04-14")
  .select($"type" cast "string", $"user_pk" cast "string", $"item_pk" cast "string")
  .as[(String,String,String)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're creating `date` column with Date type and then compare it with string??
I'd assume some implicit transformation is happening underneath (for each row while filtering).

Instead I'd convert that string to date to timestamp and do integer comparison (as you're using from_unixtime I assume timestamp is stored as System.currenttimemillis or similar):

```
timestamp = some_to_timestamp_func("2018-04-14")
df.select("type", "user_pk", "item_pk","timestamp")
  .filter($"timestamp" > timestamp)
... etc
```